# Play sound from navigation helper windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Would like to be able to play a sound from the navigation helper class (after back button handling).  Can play from a page, but can't seem to figure the logic on playing from a class with no visual elements.

Comment: From navigation helper? Can you describe the scenario? I guess you are looking to play in the apps background?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Here is the scenario:  It's an inventory/data entry page in which the user enters attributes and then the app commits the entry to a gridview.  The app plays a sound when a new item is added and then it handles the holding event on the gridview to enable deletion of a row and a sound is played there as well.  I am using the back button to enable a quick way for the user to delete the last entry.  I would like to play the delete sound here as well, but not sure how to go about accomplishing this.  Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the the following code in the page where the user would press back button:

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

In the event make the checks and play the sound and make

```
e.Handled=true;
```

this prevents the back navigation(to prevent the navigation while the sound is still playing)

When the audio has finished playing remove the handler

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

and invoke

```
Frame.GoBack();
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Really appreciate it!  Didn't realize I could handle it both at the page level and in the NavigationHelper within the same application.